# how to hide rows and columns based on a value

Tags: vba, hide

I'm having a bit of difficulty hiding rows and columns together based on cell value. I want to hide any row in column A with a cell value of "0" and Hide all columns in row 3 with a cell value of "0". There is the added twist of multiple grouping with the rows.

These two codes seem to work independently but not together when everything is ungrouped.

I would like to get them to work together and ungroup everything first because when everything is grouped it misses some "0"s.

```vb
Sub Hiderandc()

    'this code hides all rows with cell value "0"
    BeginRow = 1
    EndRow = 100
    ChkCol = 1

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Text = "0" Then
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next RowCnt

    'Description: This macro will loop through a row and
    'hide the column if the cell in row 1 of the column
    'has the value of 0.

    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Rows("1:1").Cells
        If c.Value = "0" Then
            c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            'You can change the property above to False
            'to unhide the columns.
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like you're checking row 1 instead of row 3?

Comment: good point Nathan.   also forgot to add / noticed I need the column checks to start at P to EA and row checks to start at 12 to roughly 100.

Comment: just I noticed that it appears to be checking my row with all the 0's and 1's going across.

Comment: `.usedrange.entirerow.hidden=false`

Comment: sorry haven't used usedrange before look useful I'll look at it  Thanks Nathan ! :)